# Alexa only invokes LauchRequest and not intents

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Hi I am following the fact-skill tutorial using Python for Alexa in this link:
https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-fact

My problem is that Alexa only launches the "LaunchRequest"

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # App entry point 

    #print(event)

    if event['session']['new']:
        on_session_started()

    if event['request']['type'] == "LaunchRequest":
        return on_launch(event['request'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == "IntentRequest":
        return on_intent(event['request'], event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == "SessionEndedRequest":
        return on_session_ended()
```

But it does not execute the "IntentRequest" for "GetNewFactIntent"

```
def on_intent(request, session):
    """ called on receipt of an Intent  """

    intent_name = request['intent']['name']

    # process the intents
    if intent_name == "GetNewFactIntent":
    return get_fact_response()
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.HelpIntent":
        return get_help_response()
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.StopIntent":
        return get_stop_response()
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.CancelIntent":
        return get_stop_response()
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.FallbackIntent":
        return get_fallback_response()
    else:
        print("invalid Intent reply with help")
        return get_help_response()
```

Because of this only the invocation name is valid when calling the function and the sample utterance from "GetNewFactIntent" does not call the function.
My guess is that it has problems regarding the JSON that gets passed to the AWS Lambda. It is not getting the "IntentRequest" or it cannot find

```
intent_name = request['intent']['name']
```

JSON schema:

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "space facts",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "GetNewFactIntent",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "a fact",
                        "a space fact",
                        "tell me a fact",
                        "tell me a space fact",
                        "give me a fact",
                        "give me a space fact",
                        "tell me trivia",
                        "tell me a space trivia",
                        "give me trivia",
                        "give me a space trivia",
                        "give me some information",
                        "give me some space information",
                        "tell me something",
                        "give me something"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test it on aws console?

Comment: Hi! I am not sure how to that? Did you mean the CloudWatch? Or the logs when testing? Yeah I saw Skill I/O logs, problem is it only displays when skill is successful. In this case, only the LaunchRequest event Skill Input and its Response as Skill Output.

Comment: No, you have to test it on aws lambda console, see these : 
Step 1 : https://ibb.co/iMr1eo 
Step 2 : https://ibb.co/hBd3s8 
Step 3 : https://ibb.co/keYEzo 
Step 4 : https://ibb.co/hU99X8

Comment: Test it as shown and tell me the output.

Comment: I will comment here again as soon as I look onto it. :)

Comment: I don't have a sample 'IntentRequest' though. The Skill I/O doesn't show anything when I do some 'IntentRequest'. Shall I make a dummy 'IntenRequest' ?

Comment: Okay, I used an Intent from the examples. It executed well. I guess Lambda works. However, it doesn't still work on the Alexa as well as in Developer Console. :( What's next?

Comment: Alexa replies with "I can’t find that skill. To find skills, go to the Skills section of the Alexa App."

Comment: Sooo update: My problem was I am not saying my invocation name. I thought I can skip uttering my invocation name. Anyways thanks for telling how to debug on the Lambda. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I am not telling my invocation name. So the lesson was: Before the intent, invocation first.